# Cookie with expire not accepted in latest Firexfox 60

Tags: php, firefox, setcookie

I have a small php script which is setting a cookie that should last 1 year:

```
setcookie("name", "value", 60*60*24*365);
```

This cookie is not accepted (tested in firefox & chrome) unless I use a session based cookie:

```
setcookie("name", "value", 0);
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: The third parameter should be a unix timestamp. `60*60*24*365` expires in 1971.

Comment: There does seem to be a fair amount of change with Firefox 60 as pertains to cookies though... Did something definitely 'break' on you?

Comment: Sorry for this strupid question - I just missed time() to add to 60*60*24*365... arg.